# How to collect info from attributes and send them as an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax

I want to make a JavaScript array contains the user's id of class `.user-status` to send to PHP by using ajax.

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="user-status" data-userid="159"></div>
<div class="user-status" data-userid="221"></div>
<div class="user-status" data-userid="3321"></div>
<div class="user-status" data-userid="13112"></div>
```

This is my JavaScript:

```
$('.user-status').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('data-userid');
});

var users = ["", "", "", ""];

jQuery.ajax({
    url: ajaxURL,
    data: {
        action : 'user_status',
        usersid: users
    },
    dataType: 'JSON',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (response) {

    }
});
```

Until here I can't continue I can't make the array of the user's id to can send it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create an array from list of articles tag's data attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40275338/create-an-array-from-list-of-articles-tags-data-attribute) also [Create an array of objects by capturing a data attribute](//stackoverflow.com/q/14771094)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
var users = [];
jQuery('.user-status').each(function() {
    users.push($(this).attr('data-userid');
});
```

I start with an empty array, or otherwise you'd end up with an array with 8 items, four of them empty strings.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use jquery's data property such as

```
var users = [];

$('.user-status').each(function() {
    users.push($(this).data('userid'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Push the user id into the array.

```
$('.user-status').each(function() {
    users.push($(this).attr('data-userid'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `map` along with the function `$.toArray()`

```
var users = $('.user-status').toArray().map(function(elem) {
    return $(elem).data('userid');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Array.from` you can avoid creating an empty array and push.

```js
console.log(Array.from($('.user-status'), function(element) {
return $(element).data("userid")
}))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="user-status" data-userid="159"></div>
<div class="user-status" data-userid="221"></div>
<div class="user-status" data-userid="3321"></div>
<div class="user-status" data-userid="13112"></div>
```